# Random forest importance differs between rf$importance and importance()

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest, predictor, importance

My model is working ok (the AUC is 0.7) but the importances from a `randomForest` run for my binary classification problem differ depending on how I retrieve them. Is this normal? They seem to be scaled up when I call `importance(rf)` (by order 10<sup>5</sup>). More importantly, the first three columns don't match at all, even discounting the magnitude! I'm unsure how to interpret this at the moment having read `?importance` and `?randomForest`.

Here's my randomForest call:

```
rf <- randomForest(trnX, as.factor(trnY), ntree=1000, importance=TRUE)
```

and here's a portion of the outputs:

`rf$importance`:

```
                   0             1 MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
var1   -2.308793e-05 -6.124117e-05        -3.642557e-05         30.47050
var2    6.169346e-04 -3.947637e-04         2.563570e-04         48.04932
var3    3.621287e-03  1.834355e-03         2.981152e-03         68.28302
var4    3.655234e-03  1.981978e-03         3.057267e-03         79.12254
var5    5.350649e-03  1.041555e-03         3.812376e-03         84.88832
var6    3.366199e-03  1.707144e-03         2.773894e-03         78.02293
...
```

`importance(rf)`:

```
                0          1 MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
var1   -0.4739717 -0.8497967           -0.8952541         30.47050
var2    7.9028043 -3.6680758            4.1625329         48.04932
var3   17.1279919  5.9733456           20.8354079         68.28302
var4   17.3895593  7.2370419           22.4948931         79.12254
var5   20.7470555  3.2702612           24.3069376         84.88832
var6   16.9071520  6.2532409           21.1648686         78.02293
...
```

My data has 8000 data points and 60 variables. There is definitely correlation between variables and they are of different types: some are binary flags, other are integers, others continuous. Some variables have missing values (which I'm fixing with `na.roughfix()`).

Additionally, a run from gbm:

```
gbmBernModel <- gbm(formula = var1 ~ ., distribution="bernoulli", 
                    data = trn, verbose="CV", n.trees=10000, interaction.depth=2)
```

produced relative importances (viewed by `summary(gbmBernModel)`) that made logical sense to me.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default method of `importance()` is after scaling the importance "value", i.e. for permutation based measures, the measures have been divided their “standard errors”.
While the `rf$importance` is not.

So if you try the code of

```
importance(rf, scale=FALSE)
```

The result is the same as `rf$importance`

Comment: Thanks @Vincent. From this it follows that `importance(rf)` is equivalent to `rf$importance/rf$importanceSD`